# Correctness of Converging sequence and Adherent Points

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

$x\in X$ is an **adherent point** of $A\subset X$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $y\in A$ s.t. $y\in B(x, \epsilon)$

$B(x, \epsilon)$ is the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $\epsilon$

Prove the following:

A point $x$ is an adherent point of $A$ iff there exists a sequence of points $x_n\in A$ converging to $x$.

Proof:

$\rightarrow$ Suppose $x$ is an adherent point of $A$. Then we have that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $y\in A$ s.t. $y\in B(x, \epsilon)$. This means that $d(x, y) < \epsilon$. So, consider $y_n = \{y\in A \text{ : }y=x+\frac{\epsilon}{n}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. So, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $d(x, y_n) <\epsilon$. Thus we have created a sequence in $A$ that converges to $x$.

$\leftarrow$ Suppose $x_n$ converges to $x\in A$. Then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N \implies d(x, x_n) <\epsilon$. Take $y = x_n$ for some $n>N$. Then $y \in B(x, \epsilon)$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Consider $y_n = \{y\in A \text{ : }a=x+\frac{\epsilon}{n}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. I got confused with your $y_n$.

Comment: Just incase you did not notice that. By your definition and given that the open balls centered at $x$ form neighborhood basis of $x$, the set of adherent points of $A$ is simply the closure of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently, we get the following

**Definition.** $x$ is an adherent point of $A\subseteq X$ iff for each $\epsilon>0$, $B(x,\epsilon)\cap A\neq \varnothing.$

**Theorem.** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $A\subseteq X.$  Then $x$ is an adherent point of $A$ iff there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ such that $x_n\to x.$

**Proof.** Assume that $x$ is an adherent point of $A$. Then for each $n\ge 1$, $B(x,n^{-1})\cap A\neq \varnothing.$ This means that for each $n\ge 1$, there is $x_n\in B(x,n^{-1})\cap A.$ Hence, $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $A$ such that for each $n\ge 1$, we have

$$0\le d(x_n,x)\le \frac{1}{n}$$

and thus, $x_n \to x.$

Conversely, fix a sequence $x_n$ in $A$ such that $x_n\to x.$ Let $\epsilon>0.$ Then we can choose $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(x_N,x)<\epsilon.$ Hence, for some $N\in \mathbb{N}$, we get

$$x_N\in B(x,\epsilon)\cap A,$$

showing that $B(x,\epsilon)\cap A\neq\varnothing.$ Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, it follows that $x$ is an adherent point of $A.$

Comment: is there anything wrong with my proof?

Comment: I fixed the definition of $y_n$

Comment: you treat $y_n$ as a set?

Comment: I am going for sequence... haha

Comment: I am kinda of worried that you have not replied? Is this wrong?

Comment: In your first direction, there was a confusion for your $y_n$. Hope you fix it.

Comment: Remember that your objective is to construct a sequence $(y_n)$ in $A$ such that $$d(y_n,x)\to 0 \mbox{ as } n\to +\infty$$ and that you conclude then that $y_n\to x$.

Comment: I edited my sequence. Doesn't $y_n$ converge to $x$ now?

Comment: Just a small comment: the fact that such sequence can be constructed at all requires the axiom of choice.